# Hyperbolloid Model Translations

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, isometry

Although the hyperboloid model of hyperbolic geometry has natural analogues of reflections and rotations, I am having trouble finding any linear transformation which is distance preserving and analogous to translation in Euclidean geometry. Recall that if $\textbf{v},\textbf{w} \in \mathbb{R}^n$, then our metric, $d(\cdot,\cdot)$, is derived from out inner product, the relation of which is given by $$\cosh(d(\textbf{v},\textbf{w}))=(v_1w_1-\sum_{i=2}^n v_iw_i)=\langle \textbf{v}, \textbf{w} \rangle$$ The question is simple: does there exist such a transformation and if so, what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the isometry obtained from the $n \times n$ identity matrix by replacing the upper left $2 \times 2$ submatrix with $\pmatrix{5/4 & 3/4 \\ 3/4 & 5/4}$. This matrix preserves the line which is the intersection of the hyperboloid with the $x_1,x_2$-coordinate plane, and it translates along that line.

This matrix is the one which has a "light ray" eigenvector $\pmatrix{+1 \\ +1 \\ 0 \\ \vdots}$ with eigenvalue $2$, and a "light ray" eigenvector $\pmatrix{+1 \\ -1 \\ 0 \\ \vdots}$ with eigenvalue $1/2$.

That's the typical behavior of a hyperboloid model translation: there is one light ray eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda>1$, and another light ray eigenvector with eigenvalue $1/\lambda < 1$. The line preserved by this translation is the intersection of the hyperboloid model with the plane spanned by those two eigenvectors.

Comment: Isn't that just a boost...? A boost does have the equivalent effect of translation once we project (on the Klein or Poincare disks) but it, in my mind at least, is a hyperbolic rotation, not a translation.

Comment: @Archaick: The different models are all isometric to each other, whether you choose the Klein model or the Poincare disc model or the hyperboloid model. Whether or not an isometry is a translation is an intrinsic property of the geometry, it is not a property special to any particular model. Namely, an isometry $\phi$ of $\mathbb{H}^n$ is a translation if and only if there exists an isometric embedding $\ell : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{H}^n$ and a number $T$ such that $\phi(\ell(t)) = \ell(t+T)$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: You can verify this for the example I gave, with the line $\ell$ that I described.

Comment: So, by the same reasoning I could say that a rotation about the origin in spherical geometry is also a translation?

Comment: @Archaick: Not in the same sense, because there are no isometric embeddings $\ell : \mathbb{R} \to S^n$.

Comment: Did you mean isomorphic before?

Comment: @Archaick: Every time I wrote isometric that's what I meant to write. For example, an isometric embedding $\ell : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{H}^n$ means a function that preserves distance, namely $d(\ell(s),\ell(t)) = |s-t|$. One might also call this simply a "line", but by calling it an "isometric embedding" I am emphasizing how the line is parameterized. And the parameterization is important so that the "translation equation" $\phi(\ell(t)) = \ell(t+T)$ makes sense.